# Linear Programming with Gurobi Solver

Tags: gurobi

I am trying to solve a linear optimisation problem and I keep having error messages (TypeError: 'gurobipy.LinExpr' object is not subscribable)

I am a beginner in Python. It looks like the problems are in the constraints

Please see below the codes:

```
TEST = pd.read_excel('/Users/Desktop/project/Datasets/Test2031.xlsx')
TEST_matrix = TEST.to_numpy()
Load = TEST_matrix[:500,0]
TEST_matrix = TEST.to_numpy()
Load = TEST_matrix[:500,0]
Wind = TEST_matrix[:500,1]
Solar = TEST_matrix[:500,2]
GridCFE = TEST_matrix[:500,3]
GridPrice = TEST_matrix[:500,4]
wind_slice = Wind[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
solar_slice = Solar[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
load_slice = Load [:500].flatten() # Extract desired elements
gridPrice_slice = GridPrice[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
COSTWIND = 70
COSTSOLAR = 70
target = 0.85    # Define CFE target

Wind = TEST_matrix[:500,1]
Solar = TEST_matrix[:500,2]
GridCFE = TEST_matrix[:500,3]
GridPrice = TEST_matrix[:500,4]
wind_slice = Wind[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
solar_slice = Solar[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
load_slice = Load [:500].flatten() # Extract desired elements
gridPrice_slice = GridPrice[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
COSTWIND = 70
COSTSOLAR = 70
target = 0.85    # Define CFE target

def objfunc(x):
    x1 = x[0]  # Nber of MWs of Wind
    x2 = x[1]  # Nber of MWs of Solar
    wind_slice = Wind[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    solar_slice = Solar[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    load_slice = Load [:500].flatten() # Extract desired elements
    gridPrice_slice = GridPrice[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    y = np.array([x[i] for i in range(2,502)])  # Grid MWhs
    z = np.array([x[i] for i in range(502,1002)])  # Excess WindSolar MWh

    return np.sum(x1 * wind_slice * COSTWIND) + np.sum(x2 * solar_slice * COSTSOLAR) + np.sum(gridPrice_slice * y)

def c1(x):  
    x1 = x[0]  # Nber of MWs of Wind
    x2 = x[1]  # Nber of MWs of Solar
    wind_slice = Wind[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    solar_slice = Solar[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    load_slice = Load [:500].flatten() # Extract desired elements
    gridPrice_slice = GridPrice[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    y = np.array([x[i] for i in range(2,502)])  # Grid MWhs
    z = np.array([x[i] for i in range(502,1002)])  # Excess WindSolar MWh

    return x1 * wind_slice + x2 * solar_slice + y - z - load_slice


def c2(x):
    x1 = x[0]  # Nber of MWs of Wind
    x2 = x[1]  # Nber of MWs of Solar
    wind_slice = Wind[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    solar_slice = Solar[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    load_slice = Load [:500].flatten() # Extract desired elements
    gridPrice_slice = GridPrice[:500].flatten()  # Extract desired elements
    y = np.array([x[i] for i in range(2,502)])  # Grid MWhs
    z = np.array([x[i] for i in range(502,1002)])  # Excess WindSolar MWh

    return ((np.sum(x1 * wind_slice) + np.sum(x2 * solar_slice) - np.sum(z)) / np.sum(load_slice)) - target

# Create Gurobi model
model = Model()

# Create variables
x = model.addVars(1002, lb=0, ub=10000000, name="x")

# Set objective function
obj = objfunc(x)
model.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Add constraints
model.addConstrs(c1(x)[i] == 0 for i in range(0,500))
model.addConstrs(c2(x)[i] == 0 for i in range(0,500))

# Optimize the model
model.optimize()

# Print the results
if model.status == GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print("Optimal solution found")
    print("Objective value:", model.objVal)
    print("Solution:")
    for i, var in enumerate(model.getVars()):
        print(f"Variable {i}: {var.x}")
else:
    print("Optimization failed. Status:", model.status)
```

I have been trying to make some change the range etc but it didin't work

Comment: WHERE do you see that error?  Which line?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: And, by the way, `y = x[2:502]` and `z = x[502:1002]` are better ways to do the last 2 lines of your functions.

Comment: Please revise your question as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).